# swiftui picker label visualization

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

I have an issue in label visualization with a picker inside a menu in swiftui
when the selection change the text seams to be animated in writing so it appear slowly with dot ... and and after appear all the text, but I don figure out why do this
here is the code and I attach a short gif to demonstrate the issue, it appear on canvas but also in simulator and in real device

[image: issue picker]

```
struct AddCostView: View {
    
    @State private var transactionSelectionPicker: TransactionType = .outgoing
    @State private var pickerPressed: Bool = false
    @State private var backgroundColor: String = "Outgoing"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            ZStack {
                Color(backgroundColor)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Tipo di transazione:")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        Menu {
                            Picker("transazioni", selection: $transactionSelectionPicker) {
                                ForEach(TransactionType.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { item in
                                    Text(item.rawValue)
                                        .tag(item)
                                }
                            }
                            .labelsHidden()
                            .pickerStyle(.inline)
                            .onChange(of: transactionSelectionPicker) { newValue in
                                pickerPressed.toggle()
                                switch newValue {
                                case .outgoing:
                                    backgroundColor = "Outgoing"
                                case .incoming:
                                    backgroundColor = "Incoming"
                                case .transfer:
                                    backgroundColor = "Transfer"
                                case .currecyChange:
                                    backgroundColor = "CurrencyChange"
                                }
                            }
                        } label: {
                            HStack(spacing: 8) {
                                
                                Text(transactionSelectionPicker.rawValue)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
                                    .bold()
                                    
                                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                    .rotationEffect(pickerPressed ? Angle(degrees: 90) : Angle(degrees: 0))
                                    .font(.headline)
                                
                                
                            }
                            .padding()
                            
                            
                        }
                        .frame(width: 170, alignment: .leading)
                        .background(
                            .ultraThickMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)
                        )
                        .onTapGesture {
                            pickerPressed.toggle()
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    List {
                        Text("t")
                    }
                }
                
                
                
            }
            
            
            
            .navigationTitle("Transazione")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

foreach is done with an enum I don't have animation or transaction

thanks to anyone who can help me

Comment: Did you find out how to fix it? I'm having the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem. The way I got around this was to use the `.fixedSize()` modifier. This fixes the issue of getting the `...` when the view grows in size, but it also then looks a bit weird when it shrinks. So I made a state variable and used an `.onChnage(of: value)` to check whether the new value was longer or shorter and then applied the `.fixedSize()` only in the case the new value was longer. This is a rough idea of how it looks.

```
@State private var isLonger = true
@State private var value = "initial value"
...

// value here is the variable that stores the current selection value for the picker
var body: some View {
  PickerView
    .onChange(of: value) { [value] newValue in
      isLonger = newValue.count > value.count
    }

}

var PickerView: some View {
  if isLonger {
    MenuPicker()
      .fixedSize()
  } else {
    MenuPicker()
  }
}
```